# What's the difference between flow and channelFlow?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have both codes below, and the result looks the same for me

```
val namesFlow = flow {
    println("Start flow")
    (0..10).forEach {
        // Emit items with 500 milliseconds delay
        delay(500)
        println("Emitting $it")
        emit(it)
    }
}.map { it * it }

fun main() = runBlocking {
    namesFlow.collect { println(it) }
    namesFlow.collect { println(it) }
    println("Finish Flow")
}
```

and

```
val namesFlow = channelFlow {
    println("Start flow")
    (0..10).forEach {
        // Emit items with 500 milliseconds delay
        delay(500)
        println("Emitting $it")
        send(it)
    }
}.map { it * it }

fun main() = runBlocking {
    namesFlow.collect { println(it) }
    namesFlow.collect { println(it) }
    println("Finish Flow")
}
```

What's the difference between `flow` and `channelFlow`?

Answer (score 7):

The purpose of `channelFlow` is being able to retrieve the results from a concurrently running coroutine. Here's an example from its [documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/channel-flow.html) that merges another flow into the current one by concurrently collecting both the current and the other flow, sending all the data to the same channel:

```kotlin
fun <T> Flow<T>.merge(other: Flow<T>): Flow<T> = channelFlow {
    launch {
        collect { send(it) }
    }
    other.collect { send(it) }
}
```

Since your code makes no use of the ability to call `send` from a concurrent coroutine (something you can't do with `emit`), both examples in your question have the same behavior.